# Construct an Orthogonal basis for the subspace $W\subseteq R^3$. given by the following basis:

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

Construct an Orthogonal basis for the subspace $W\subseteq R^3$.  given by the following basis:

$\{\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\}$,
$\{\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
5 \\
-6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\}$

Okay so I have never been asked to find a basis given a basis set. This is how I did it, is this correct?

I made the first vector in the basis x and the second y. so

X= $\{\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\}$          and y=$\{\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
5 \\
-6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\}$

Then using the formulas: q1= x/$\|x\|$, y'=y-($q1^T$*y)*q1 and
y'/$\|y'\|$.

I get the following basis:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
 3\\
0 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\}$          and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
5 \\
-3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\}$

Comment: Your answer is fine.  Just a little note: It asks for an orthogonal basis, not an orthonormal basis, so there's no reason to scale them.  Meaning $$\left\{\pmatrix{3 \\ 0 \\ -1}, \pmatrix{-1 \\ 5 \\ -3}\right\}$$ would also have been fine.

Comment: Have I lost my mind or did I see this question yesterday as well?